# Error handling with Async/Await in Stripe API JS

Tags: javascript, error-handling, async-await, stripe-payments, fetch-api

I'm playing with the Stripe API. Everything works great, but I want to show possible configurations fails in the frontend. Those fails are handled as an 500.

So this is the condensed code

JS

```
async function initialize() {
    const { clientSecret } = await fetch("index.php?format=json", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify({ id: myid, lang: mylang }),
    }).then((r) => {
        if (r.status >= 400 && r.status < 600) {
            // throw new Error(r.status);
        }
        return r.json()
    }

    ).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
    }
    );

    console.log(clientSecret);

}
```

PHP

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
try {
    // code doing some stuff ...
    $output = [
        'secret' => 12345
    ];
    echo json_encode($output);
} catch (Error $e) {
    http_response_code(500);
    echo json_encode(['error' => $e->getMessage()]);
}
```

When having a misconfiguration, this is (for example) what the fetch call outputs:

```
{
    "error": true,
    "code": 0,
    "message": "The payment method type provided: acss_debit is invalid. This payment method is available to Stripe accounts in CA and US and your Stripe account is in XX.",
}
```

So how can I catch that error message in JS and display it to the user?
I tried all kind of stuff in the initialize function.

Comment: "*The [provided data] is invalid*" should not be a 500 error. It's a 400 error.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to access the catched error message by doing this:

```
if (r.status >= 400 && r.status < 600) {

    return r.text()
        .then((text) => {
            throw (JSON.parse(text));
        });
}
```